# How to skip to next person when the date is within a specific range?

Tags: vba, excel

I m going to count every staff member's accumulative balance. The accumulative balance should be counted by person. There are some conditions:

1) The accumulative balance should be counted only before "01/01/2016" and most closest to "01/01/2016".

2) Also, if each person has any record between "01/01/2016" and "31/03/2016", no need to record his/her balance anymore and shift to next person.

[image]

Here is the sample. S15 dosen't have a record between that range and the most closest balance to "01/01/2016" is 31. S98 has record between that range. Hence, his record should be ignored.

The output should be:

- S15  31

---

My code here:

```
Sub gg()

    Dim startdate As Date
    Dim curr, neww As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim closest As Integer
    Dim range As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = worksheet1
    With ws
        Dim enddate As Date

        i = 2
        j = 2
        startdate = "01/01/2016"
        enddate = "31/03/2016"
        closest = 2

        range = enddate - startdate
        Do While .Cells(i, 2) <> 0
            If (.Cells(i, 2) >= startdate Or .Cells(i, 2) <= enddate) Then

                Do While .Cells(i + 1, 1) = .Cells(i, 1)
                    i = i + 1
                Loop
                i = i + 1
            End If
            '''
            curr = .Cells(i, 2) - startdate
            ''
            If (.Cells(i, 2) - startdate) <= curr Then
                neww = (.Cells(i, 2) - startdate)
                closest = closest + 1
            End If
            If (.Cells(i + 1, 1)) <> .Cells(i, 1) Then
                .Cells(j, 5) = .Cells(i, 1)
                .Cells(j, 6) = .Cells(closest, 3)
                curr = .Cells(i + 1, 2) - startdate

                j = j + 1
            End If

            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

---

I guess the probematic part is here  .

It can't select the date between that range and skip to next person .

```
If (.Cells(i, 2) >= startdate Or .Cells(i, 2) <= enddate) Then

    Do While .Cells(i + 1, 1) = .Cells(i, 1)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    i = i + 1
End If
```

Comment: Where is the S19?  I do not see him in your graph.

Comment: @pcw It should be s98 . I correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** to sort final output and remove its blanks

I'd use [RemoveDuplicates()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823(v=office.15).aspx) and [AutoFilter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) methods of `Range` object like follows (see comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As range

    With Worksheets("balance") '<--| change name with your actual worksheet name
        With .range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)) '<--| consider your actual data: form cell "A1" down to last non empty cell of column "C"
            With .Resize(, .Columns.Count + 2) '<--| consider the range expanded rightwards two columns from the last one
                With .Columns(.Columns.Count) '<--| consider "new" last column
                    .value = .Parent.Columns(1).value '<--| copy StaffID values from column "A"
                    .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), header:=xlYes '<--| remove StaffID duplicates
                    .Offset(, 1).Resize(1) = "Balance" '<-- add header "Balance" in one column left first row
                End With
                For Each cell In .Columns(.Columns.Count).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| loop through unique values
                    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=cell.value '<--| filter column "A" (StaffID) with values corresponding to current unique StaffID value
                    .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="<01/03/2016" '<--| filter column "B" (dates) with dates preceeding "1/3/2016" only
                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell has been filtered...
                        With .Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| ... consider column "B" (dates) filtered cells...
                            cell.Offset(, 1) = GetMaxDate(.Cells, Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(.Cells)) '...and get the balance corresponding to highest visible date and store next to StaffID unique value
                       End With
                    Else '<--| otherwise...
                        cell.ClearContents '<--|... clear "invalid" StaffID unique value
                    End If
                    .AutoFilter '<--| show all rows back...
                Next cell
                With .Columns(.Columns.Count) '<--| consider "new" last column
                    range(.range("A1"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Sort key1:=.range("A1"), header:=xlYes '<--| sort it by its first column ('StaffID') and remove blanks
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Function GetMaxDate(rng As range, dt As Date) As Double
    Dim cell As range
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.value = dt Then Exit For
    Next cell
    GetMaxDate = cell.Offset(, 1).value
End Function
```

Comment: i test ur code . Just one problem . The result is okay .But the result 1 and result 2 have skipped 2 lines . I just want to place the result in every lines

Comment: Please explain in better detail

Comment: For example , there are 3 staffID and it should be displayed 3 results . The first result is on row 2 ,the second result is on row 4 .... I don't want any space between the results.

Comment: That was not specified in your question. As per this site rule you should accept the answer that match the _original_ question, and post a new question for any new (i.e. not contained in the _original_ question) request along with your code attempts at solving it. Anyhow see edited code